# Removing and replacing PRV from water boiler

Tags: plumbing, boiler, copper-pipe

The pressure relief valve on my boiler is rated for 30psi but is weeping water on the discharge line at around 25-27 psi so it seems it needs to be replaced. Unfortunately the valve does not seem to have been installed with replacement in mind. My guess is I need to cut at least one copper line and my initial guess is that the best candidate is the horizontal coming out of the pressure relief valve. My question is, what next? What kind of union may I install and how would I go about it in order to future-proof the ability to replace the PRV?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that is not an union at the copper pipe to relieve valve?

Comment: no it looks like a fixed male thread into the relief valve.

Comment: @ratchetfreak is correct. It is only a threaded adaptor to the crimp style connection to the copper pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the 90 elbow before the PRV and all the copper after it.

Replace that short nipple with a longer one that extends past the edge of the boiler.  Mount the PRV directly to it, so its outlet faces down.  Screw on a short straight piece of threaded pipe (eg a 24 inch nipple), just enough to direct water towards the floor.  You're not meant to have extensive pipery after the PRV anyway so this simplifies and solves your problem.   Next time you just have to unscrew the straight pipe then the valve. No unions needed.

NOTE: Some PRV instructions say they must be installed in a certain orientation.   Others allow them to be installed vertically or horizontally.    The 90 degree elbow may be there for a good reason, or maybe just the installer's habit or precaution.   Since you're buying a new one, buy one where the instructions permit installation the way I suggest.

Comment: Thank you @jay613, that's a good suggestion.